# My jsp gives Generated servlet error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Tags: java, jsp

I've tried the double backslash thing, but it keeps giving me the same error. Provided below is the code I am using:

```
<%@ page  import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page  import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page  import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.HashMap"%>
<%@ page  import="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ page  import="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Planning</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Planning</h2>
        <%
            Connection conn = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DC1VCWSQL105\sql05:1433;databaseName=TD_DA_Test;integratedSecurity=True");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();


        }
        File reportFile = new File(application.getRealPath("//bespoke//rapport//Planning.jasper"));
        Map parameters = new HashMap();
        byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    %>

</body>
```

How come the \ do not work in my case?
The exact error is:

An error has occurred:

```
PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /bespoke/rapportplanning/Planning.jsp PWC6199: Generated servlet error: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )  
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Unable to compile class for JSP PWC6197
```

Comment: You probably mean '\\' or '/' in this line: `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DC1VCWSQL105\sql05:1433;databaseName=TD_DA_Test;integratedSecurity=True");
`. (Note the `\s` there)

Comment: Code does not belong in JSPs.  This is a 1998 vintage idea.  What's even more remarkable is that you're aware of JSTL.   Why not use the <sql> tags?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am working with a piece of heritage, will change to JSTL <sql>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @S.R.I mentioned, a "\" in a `String` has to be escaped: "\". The correct line would be:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DC1VCWSQL105\\sql05:1433;databaseName=TD_DA_Test;integratedSecurity=True");
```

Comment: It might even do to use `/` instead of `\\` (URL syntax).

Comment: That's true. I didn't validate the URL, I just corrected the immediate error.

Answer (score 1):

A better way could be -

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@amrood:1521:EMP";
String user = "username";
String pass = "password"
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

Or you can move these properties in a property file then use -

```
DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your connection url

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DC1VCWSQL105\sql05:1433;databaseName=TD_DA_Test;integratedSecurity=True
```

Java compiler will treat `\s` as an escape and cause it's not a valid escape. So the error occured.

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )
```

Using `\\s` instead and Java compiler will treat `\\` as an escape and `s` as a char.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character here is some info about escape characters and sequences.
Your code has an escape character `\` which have to be followed with proper escape sequence, in your case, as I see, you want to have single `\` in your string, if so, just type `\\` there, this escape sequence will be replaced with only one `\` in your output string.